# Google App Engine and CORS

Tags: java, jquery, google-app-engine, cors

I have a simple app (java servlet) hosted on GAE. The app returns json data. I have set the header info as following in the servlet:

```
resp.setContentType("application/json");
resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

Here's the header info when I go to the URL directly on the app engine:

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:---------.appspot.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko)         Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:340
Content-Type:application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Sat, 28 Apr 2012 19:14:58 GMT
Server:Google Frontend
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

But when I try to access the url from a different domain I get the following response:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, x-requested-with, accept
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:----------.appspot.com
Origin:http://--------------.com
Referer:http://-------------.com/map/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:466
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sat, 28 Apr 2012 19:15:14 GMT
Server:Google Frontend
```

here is the exact error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://----------.appspot.com/Locations. Origin http://-------------.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The code that tries to access the GAE url looks like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://---------appspot.com/Locations",function(result){
    for (i=0; i < result.length; i++)
```

Any help would be much appreciate it.

Comment: Your app is returning a 500, which probably means it's throwing an uncaught exception. Check your logs to see why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to override standard HttpServlet.doOptions() method to support proper [pre-flight request processing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

```
@Override
protected void doOptions(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException 
{ 
    // pre-flight request processing
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", SUPPORTED_METHODS);
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", SUPPORTED_HEADERS);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
   resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   resp.setContentType("application/json");

   // implementation...
}
```

A great article explaining CORS with examples can be found [here](https://reflectoring.io/complete-guide-to-cors/).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your request is failing early, on a [preflight request](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/cors/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#preflight-request), because the server responses with 500 (it should respond with 200 + specific headers) when being requested `OPTIONS <URL>`.

You might want to check out [HTML5rocks tutorial on CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), specifically Adding CORS support to the server, where preflight request is explained (the `OPTIONS <url>` request, on which your app fails to reply with 200 + required headers).

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution (Work for me):

1. Config CORS support in your Java App Engine project:

With mvn put in your pom.xml file:

```
<!-- CORS Support for Jetty -->
<dependency>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <version>9.2.22.v20170606</version>
</dependency>
```

Or with jar file downloaded: [jetty-servlets.jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg:%22org.eclipse.jetty%22%20AND%20a:%22jetty-servlets%22), put it in your WEB-INF/lib

2. Config your web.xml file:

   `<filter>
   <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
   <param-value>*</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
   <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
   <param-value>X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin</param-value>
   </init-param>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>`

Maybe you need change ***allowedOrigins*** field value with a custom URL.

Thats all, build and happy coding.

*For aditional information:* [How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to jetty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037558/how-to-add-access-control-allow-origin-to-jetty-server)

Comment: What if we don't have web.xml file?

Comment: The web.xml file is neccesary for java web apps.

Comment: in latest servlet technology.. we no need to maintain web.xml file instead of that we can annotate by "@WebServlet"  "@WebListener" etc

Comment: oh I see, then you need know how to put annotation for CORS.