# How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to jetty server

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I've got a jetty server to run my web services. Recently I developed a program to consume the web service and ran into Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue.

How can I add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to a jetty embedded server.

below is the webappcontext code.

```
public WebAppContext buildWebAppContext(){
    webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
    webAppContext.setDescriptor(webAppContext + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    webAppContext.setResourceBase(".");
    webAppContext.setContextPath("/posApplication");
    webAppContext.setAttribute("webContext", webAppContext);
    return webAppContext;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Setup the [`org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/CrossOriginFilter.html) in your web app.

Old question/answer on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8454168/775715

See Jetty [Documentation Hub](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/) on [CrossOriginFilter Use](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/cross-origin-filter.html):

**Quick Start**

1. Grab yourself a copy of [jetty-servlets.jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg:%22org.eclipse.jetty%22%20AND%20a:%22jetty-servlets%22).
2. Put the `jetty-servlets.jar` in your `WEB-INF/lib`
3. Add the following to your `WEB-INF/web.xml`

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Note that wildcards like "*" are not allowed for headers. I had to explicitly provide a list of the headers for it to work. See killer7's answer in the question you've linked.

Comment: When this was answered, back in Apr 2013, it was correct.  Things have changed since then.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt can you please link me to a correct solution? this one is not working for me

Comment: Thanks, do I need to rename it to java-servlets.jar? Does it get automatically picked up? Only with that name rather than jetty-servlets-9.4.9.v20180320?

Comment: @Dominic that's a good candidate for a new question as it depends on your setup (using newer `jetty-home-<ver>.tar.gz`? or older `jetty-distribution-<ver>.tar.gz`? or standalone? or jetty-runner? or jetty-maven-plugin? or embedded-jetty?)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this CORS problem is to use an extension in chrome/chromium browser. here is the link for the extension.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

No need to add any headers in the server side code(which will obviously work but may not be a good idea).

Comment: Another workaround is to just launch Chrome without CORS rules. Quit Chrome completely. Then open a terminal and execute: open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir