# Jetty embedded HTTP server Access Control Allow Origin

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm embedding a Jetty server within my Java package and I want to query this server through another origin. I currently do not have a web app, this is just a server that I set up to run. I am new to Jetty and would appreciate an explanation as to why the following code is getting the error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9888/demo/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

public class EmbeddingJettyWithServlet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(9888);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/demo");
        server.setHandler(context);
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new MyThriftServlet()), "/*");
        server.start();
    }
}
```

I've searched online and kept seeing answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037558/how-to-add-access-control-allow-origin-to-jetty-server) where I'm supposed to change WEB-INF/web.xml. But I don't have a WEB-INF folder because this isn't a webapp and the code above is just another class. How do I allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin with this?

Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29970226/5273299) may be what you're looking for.