# UnavailableException when trying to set up Jetty CORS access

Tags: java, jetty, geoserver, http-status-code-503

I've been trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037558/how-to-add-access-control-allow-origin-to-jetty-server) and linked within answers to try and setup a CORS access as apparently `localhost` and `localhost:8080` are two different domains. *sigh*

Either way, the issue I'm having is that when starting the server a `javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter` exception is thrown. I've no clue what's causing it.

When trying to use the services in it I get a 503 error.

Steps taken:

1. Copied the `jetty-servlet-9.2.13.v20150730.jar` from the Geoserver `lib` folder to the `webapps` `WEB-INF`'s `lib` folder.
2. Pasted the following into my `web.xml`: [Pastebin because editor didn't cooperate](http://pastebin.com/ag13FDpW)

If I remove those lines it works fine, apart from the CORS issues I have. (I'm trying to access colour values of specific pixels.

Other than that and an added WMS, the Geoserver instance is pretty much a fresh install.

UPDATE:

So, following @sideshowbarker's advice, I have inserted a `servlets` file. Now I'm getting a 404 error, seemingly caused by the GeoServer setup not being able to find the definition of `org/eclipse/jetty/util/StringUtil`. Errr, what?

Please find the pastebin of this: http://pastebin.com/4R8hZNcM

## UPDATE 2:

So, I've inserted the required `jar` into the `WEB-INF` folder, and now it's throwing a `NoSuchMethodError` in regards to the `csvSplit` method... what? o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jetty-util had a faulty StringUtil class, with a faulty csvSplit method. Replacing this with the most recent (9.4.*) jar solved the issue.