# Unable to access NIFI Rest api of another server in secured mode

Tags: ajax, rest, apache-nifi

I am trying to access NIFI rest api of another server from my machine using ajax like below,

```
url:"https://serverip:port/nifi-api/",
{Authorization : 'Bearer ' + 'access token here'}
```

> Getting Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache NiFi's API is designed to be invoked by a variety of clients, but in this case I think you are encountering a security precaution put in place by [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

If a piece of code on server A (your non-NiFi machine) makes an AJAX request to a different origin (your NiFi instance), and the HTTP method is not `GET` (and some other minor restrictions), server A will first send a "preflight" request, which is HTTP `OPTIONS`, to the remote instance to determine what requests are valid. A server can reply to this with the header [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin), which is a wildcard value denoting it accepts requests from any origin. However, if you want to send credentials along with the request, the originating hostname must be explicitly listed in the response (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://serverA.com`).

Because NiFi uses an embedded Jetty server to host the API, you may have to explicitly add a [`CrossOriginFilter`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/cross-origin-filter.html) as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16043524/70465).

Comment: Hi Andy,
Tried to add filter as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037558/how-to-add-access-control-allow-origin-to-jetty-server/16043524#16043524
but still getting the same error
**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://serverA://port' is therefore not allowed access.**

Comment: If you use the Developer Tools or curl to make an AJAX request can you see the response and examine the response headers? It seems that the filter is not putting the proper header on the response. (Also "`serverA://port`" seems incorrect...).

Comment: Hi Andy, resolved issue by adding filters **before** the existing filter section.
Reference :http://marianoguerra.org/posts/enable-cors-in-apache-solr.html

Comment: Hi Andy,cross origin filters not working in IE and Microsoft edge.Do you  have any idea?