# How to serve Angular app on a different port to my http server

Tags: angular, cors

In development mode I am using Angular2 CLI's "ng serve" command to serve the application on localhost:4200. This is great because any tweak to a source file causes a rapid rebuild and the browser to automatically reload the changes.

My app makes http requests to a RESTful api on a Jetty server running on localhost:8080. But all the requests fail with the very unhelpful: "EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0 for URL null". If instead I also serve the Angular app from the Jetty server by pointing it at the client project's dist directory, everything works fine. From looking up questions about similar problems, I gather that it might be a Cross-Origin-Request (CORS) problem.

But if I have to serve the client app from the same server/port as my RESTful api I lose the advantages of auto-rebuild/reload that I get from "ng serve". An "ng build" is slower.

Is there any way around this?

**UPDATE:**

As confirmed in the answers this is a CORS issue. I managed to fix it by filtering requests on the server side with an `org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter`. However, I've selected the use of  `ng build -o dist -w` as the answer, because that fixes my slower build problem, in which case I'm happy to just point my Jetty server at the client files in the dist directory and serve everything (client and api) from the same port.

Comment: I believe you simply need to set CORS.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037558/how-to-add-access-control-allow-origin-to-jetty-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CORS related issue but to answer your question you can use different ports with ng serve using the -p flag: `ng serve -p 8080`

You can also use the `-w` flag to "watch" file changes when you run `ng build`, that way it will update that dist directory you'd be pointing to as changes are made.

Comment: Perhaps I was trying to solve the wrong problem. The -w flag cures my slower build problem, making it more attractive to just point my web server at the dist directory. Although I have managed to fix the CORS problem too, so I have a choice of two approaches now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a CORS issue. Your API needs to return a proper Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in it's response.

An example of how to do this with Spring Boot can be found at http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-2-spring-boot-jwt-cors_part1

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Unfortunately all the examples are very configuration specific, and in my case I'm using: embedded Jetty with no web.xml, and Google Guice dependency injection using the hk2-to-Guice bridge. I finally figured out how to do it programatically using Guice's ServletModule to install a CrossOriginFilter.