# sgVizler - Remove Base URL

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sparql, sgvizler

```js
//Initialize sgvizler Query for actors
var A = new sgvizler.Query();

A.query(" PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> PREFIX am: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/actor_name> SELECT ?actorName ?actorLink  WHERE { ?actorLink am: 'Christian Bale' . ?actorLink am: ?actorName . } ")
  .endpointURL("http://data.linkedmdb.org/sparql")
  .endpointOutputFormat("jsonp")
  .chartFunction("sgvizler.visualization.Table")
  .draw("searchResults");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/2.10.0/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mgskjaeveland.github.io/sgvizler/v/0.6/sgvizler.js"></script>


<div id="searchResults"> </div>
```

I'm using Sgvizler 0.6 to visualize some SPARQL queries but for some reason, when a link is returned and I try to click on it the baseURL + the real URL are returned. Is there some way to remove the baseURL and leave only the URL to the actual web page ?

Comment: Probably this: https://github.com/mgskjaeveland/sgvizler/issues/67

Comment: @StanislavKralin for this I should download the script, fix it and then add the script locally and not with `<script src="" ..... </script>, right ?

Comment: Most likely, yes.

Comment: Yes github.com/mgskjaeveland/sgvizler/issues/67 is the answer to this problem. Thank you @StanislavKralin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an error in the code, where instead of the function that handles the hrefs, only the name of the function was returned. In order to fix the problem a new version of the code was uploaded. Changing the script source to `<script src="https://mgskjaeveland.github.io/sgvizler/v/0.7/sgvizler.js"></script>` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with Sgvizler2. I have an error message in the javascript console log :

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://bordercloud.github.io' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

You need to configure your SPARQL service to allow another origin and it will work with Sgvizler.

May be, your problem is in relation with the configuration of your Jetty server : [How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to jetty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037558/how-to-add-access-control-allow-origin-to-jetty-server)

Comment: try to change the Output format from `json` to `jsonp` and this problem will disappear. Also I can't change the server configuration as I send the queries directly to the SPARQL-Endpoint.

Comment: @JohnDoe with format jsonp I have an error 500. I tested with this form : https://bordercloud.github.io/sgvizler2/tutorial-A_Editor.html

Comment: That's funny normally if you use the original script sgVizler you get the results the the query. If  the output format is json you also get the CORS error but if you change it to jsonp everything's fine.