# Angular 6 - Spring MVC :: Options preflight request throws 500 internal Server Error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cors, angular6, preflight

**Intention:**
***Consume a REST API in Angular that is exposed via a SpringMVC based web application.  Both are running in different hosts***

**Problem**:

Although the API I am requesting is a `GET` Request, Angular *behind-the-scenes* first makes an `OPTIONS` request to the REST API SpringMVC server.  This throws back a `500` server error (see `CURL` output below).

Tried hitting the same API using Postman tool (`GET` request), surprisingly its giving desired output (i.e. also gives `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header) without any error, but `OPTIONS` request throws 500 server error.

**Tech Stack I am using**:

- `Angular 6` (runs atop `NodeJS`)
- `Spring MVC 4.3.6.RELEASE` (with ***no*** Spring security *explicitly* configured) [*Java config* based Spring configuration]
- `Jetty-Runner 9.4.1` (to run the WAR file of Spring MVC webapp).

**Error Message got by Angular:**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/v1/create' from origin
 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**Code Snippets:**

*Angular code:*

```
public createDomainObj() {           
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/v1/create', request body parameter)
}
```

*SpringMVC code:*

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@AccessController(accessLevel = "Anonymous")
public <APIResponseModelClass> anAPIMethod(@RequestBody param1, param2) {
    //code logic 
    return <obj>;
}
```

**What's tried already:**

CORS Filter in SpringMVC, all combinations of Annotations, but no luck.

Have also tried suggestions mentioned in below links to no success:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cors-preflight

[How to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to jetty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037558/how-to-add-access-control-allow-origin-to-jetty-server)

**`CURL` is able to reproduce the problem:**

**REQUEST**:

```
curl -H "Origin:*" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE" 
-H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" 
-X OPTIONS --verbose  http://localhost:8080/v1/create
```

**RESPONSE**:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
 Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
 OPTIONS /v1/create HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:8080
 User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
 Accept: */*
 Origin:*
 Access-Control-Request-Method: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
 Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With
 Content-Length: 392
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 upload completely sent off: 392 out of 392 bytes
 HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
 Connection: close
Server: Jetty(9.4.2.v20170220)
Closing connection 0
```

---

**So, how to make Angular to consume the REST API from SpringMVC that has OPTIONS preflight aspect?**

Comment: are you using `spring-security` ? try reading https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: can you please add your failing code??

Answer (score 1):

I can say about issue,
`CORS:Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control`,
There are two types of requests,
1) Simple
Have some criteria, simple exchange of cors headers, allowed methods, headers, content-types
2) preflight
Those doesnt match simple request criteria are preflight, for example,
we send a DELETE request to the server. The browser sends OPTIONS request with headers containing info about the DELETE request we made.

```
OPTIONS /users/:id 
Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
```

simple thing to fix is you can remove or change any complex headers that aren't needed.

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` setting this will work for simple CORS requests, so for more complex request having custom headers value wont work, thats the preflight mechanism of the browser it checks that service accepts request or not,
remeber that it includeds,

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Request-Method
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

it seems you need to add cors in http configure thats cors filter,
different ways enabling cors,
1) Controller method CORS configuration

```
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
  @GetMapping("/greeting")
  public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    System.out.println("==== in greeting ====");
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
  }
```

2) Global CORS configuration

```
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
      }
    };
  }
```

3) Enabling webSecurity, try adding `http.cors()`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // ...
        http.cors();
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with more details with failing code, which will gives more clarification about problem , request to please check now and provide your thoughts?

Comment: @AmrutaShiralkar Good Question