# cross-domain jQuery ajax call fails for valid resource

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

The code attempts to make a cross-domain call using [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        var request=$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://2.cinema-sderot.appspot.com/getSimpleJson",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true
        });

        request.done(function( msg ) {
          $("div").append("Done");
        });

        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
          $("div").append("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Even though the URL [returns a valid JSON](http://2.cinema-sderot.appspot.com/getSimpleJson), the code fails with the message `Request failed: error`. I did not find any useful information in the console log, both in Firefox and Chrome.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I have handled such situations by creating a proxy script on server which call the remote url via curl.Not sure its a best approach or relevant in your case so not posting as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you say `crossDomain: true` if the requesting resource is not supporting cross domain request using CORS the request will fail

In this case the server does not seems to be supporting CORS.

If you are using java servlets add the following herader

```
resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Comment: Any idea how to enable it? The resource is a Google App I've written.

Comment: @AdamMatan what is the serverside technology used? java?

Comment: @AdamMatan see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366912/google-app-engine-and-cors

Comment: Thanks, adding `resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` to the response solved it. Want to add it to your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41189/discussion-between-adam-matan-and-arun-p-johny)