# How to enable CORS between Firebase Hosting and Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cors

I have hosted my SPA in Firebase Hosting, and my API Nodejs server in Google App Engine. Now I'm stuck at enabling CORS when calling an endpoint from my SPA.

I have tried adding it in my `app.yaml` with no luck:

```
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_dir: /
    http_headers:
      Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

Any other ideas?

EDIT:
I would like to also avoid using the `cors` npm package cuz I think CORS handling should be done at the network level like Nginx but what is the equivalent of Nginx in GAE?

Answer (score 2):

I understand your point and concerns, but I would recommend you to set the CORS properly, for the Firebase and App Engine to work properly.

Considering that, I searched for some sources and articles that might help you configure it, including options that you might find a better fit for your needs.

- [CORS on App Engine](https://enable-cors.org/server_appengine.html)
  [Handlers Element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#handlers_element)
- [Google App Engine and CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366912/google-app-engine-and-cors)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Referring to this doc https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#handlers_http_headers, I tried adding it to the `app.yaml`'s `handlers` but didn't work..

Comment: Hi @kyw it seems as mentioned on this post [here](https://github.com/riannucci/rietveldv2/issues/27) that `http_headers` doesn't work on script languages. For this reason, there are some workarounds for this type of languages. Could you please give it a try checking this mentioned post and give it a try?

Comment: Thanks for helping, gso_gabriel. I can't find `position` and `script` documented in the `app.yaml` doc. Currently, I'm using the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) npm package and it works. But I'm not sure that's the idiomatic way of doing CORS in GAE w.r.t API endpoints..

Comment: @kyw Yes, this is not mentioned in the documentation. This seems to be found only if you access the configuration files from App Engine. For your case, searching further, that workaround seems to be viable only to PHP. I believe that using the CORS npm package it's the best alternative for you.

Comment: Alright I will stick to the cors npm package for now. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Hi @kyw if you think my answer helped you, please, consider upvoting or accepting it. :)