# GCP receives request as type OPTIONS and functionality breaks

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to send a request from my front-end to my back-end comprised of Java Servlets but for some reason GCP receives the request as an OPTIONS type instead of a PUT or DELETE and then none of the functionality or logging works, GET and POST work fine.

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog",
    "appId": "g~servletcoursework-336513",
    "versionId": "20211231t193717",
    "requestId": "61cf5ebf00ff0c34825de6b9a60001677e736572766c6574636f75727365776f726b2d3333363531330001323032313132333174313933373137000100",
    "ip": "84.70.147.60",
    "startTime": "2021-12-31T19:49:19.801880Z",
    "endTime": "2021-12-31T19:49:19.814140Z",
    "latency": "0.012260s",
    "method": "OPTIONS",
    "resource": "/deleteFilm?format=xml&id=10001",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
    "status": 200,
    "responseSize": "68",
    "referrer": "https://d2icepsfo58cxr.cloudfront.net/",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36",
    "urlMapEntry": "unused",
    "host": "servletcoursework-336513.nw.r.appspot.com",
    "cost": 7.598999999999999e-9,
    "instanceIndex": -1,
    "finished": true,
    "instanceId": "00c61b117c8704a9c5c71617a78aab0d6d5dd3630b836d3885a5565c92e147a58efbc9180d22c59db107f4946306db18bbe33383d93470f26dada4e4acbd199e9d276494d392ba7d0b",
    "appEngineRelease": "1.9.71",
    "traceId": "0184c35a91f8e703c73e9f79e6a522e6",
    "first": true,
    "traceSampled": true
  },
  "insertId": "61cf5ebf000c6cc558e7834c",
  "httpRequest": {
    "status": 200
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "gae_app",
    "labels": {
      "zone": "europe-west2-2",
      "project_id": "servletcoursework-336513",
      "version_id": "20211231t193717",
      "module_id": "default"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-12-31T19:49:19.801880Z",
  "labels": {
    "clone_id": "00c61b117c8704a9c5c71617a78aab0d6d5dd3630b836d3885a5565c92e147a58efbc9180d22c59db107f4946306db18bbe33383d93470f26dada4e4acbd199e9d276494d392ba7d0b"
  },
  "logName": "projects/servletcoursework-336513/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log",
  "operation": {
    "id": "61cf5ebf00ff0c34825de6b9a60001677e736572766c6574636f75727365776f726b2d3333363531330001323032313132333174313933373137000100",
    "producer": "appengine.googleapis.com/request_id",
    "first": true,
    "last": true
  },
  "trace": "projects/servletcoursework-336513/traces/0184c35a91f8e703c73e9f79e6a522e6",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-12-31T19:49:19.816277372Z",
  "traceSampled": true
}
```

Yet if I do the same request via Postman it works completely fine:

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog",
    "appId": "g~servletcoursework-336513",
    "versionId": "20211231t193717",
    "requestId": "61cf5f9300ff023d16e28dbc540001677e736572766c6574636f75727365776f726b2d3333363531330001323032313132333174313933373137000100",
    "ip": "54.86.50.139",
    "startTime": "2021-12-31T19:52:51.186694Z",
    "endTime": "2021-12-31T19:52:51.227747Z",
    "latency": "0.041053s",
    "megaCycles": "4000",
    "method": "DELETE",
    "resource": "/deleteFilm?format=xml&id=10001",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
    "status": 200,
    "responseSize": "195",
    "userAgent": "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4",
    "urlMapEntry": "unused",
    "host": "servletcoursework-336513.nw.r.appspot.com",
    "cost": 2.1792e-8,
    "instanceIndex": -1,
    "finished": true,
    "instanceId": "00c61b117c8704a9c5c71617a78aab0d6d5dd3630b836d3885a5565c92e147a58efbc9180d22c59db107f4946306db18bbe33383d93470f26dada4e4acbd199e9d276494d392ba7d0b",
    "appEngineRelease": "1.9.71",
    "traceId": "4700825c5878ed9191d27216bd8b752a",
    "first": true,
    "traceSampled": true
  },
  "insertId": "61cf5f9300037a2457bd3063",
  "httpRequest": {
    "status": 200
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "gae_app",
    "labels": {
      "version_id": "20211231t193717",
      "zone": "europe-west2-2",
      "project_id": "servletcoursework-336513",
      "module_id": "default"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-12-31T19:52:51.186694Z",
  "labels": {
    "clone_id": "00c61b117c8704a9c5c71617a78aab0d6d5dd3630b836d3885a5565c92e147a58efbc9180d22c59db107f4946306db18bbe33383d93470f26dada4e4acbd199e9d276494d392ba7d0b"
  },
  "logName": "projects/servletcoursework-336513/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log",
  "operation": {
    "id": "61cf5f9300ff023d16e28dbc540001677e736572766c6574636f75727365776f726b2d3333363531330001323032313132333174313933373137000100",
    "producer": "appengine.googleapis.com/request_id",
    "first": true,
    "last": true
  },
  "trace": "projects/servletcoursework-336513/traces/4700825c5878ed9191d27216bd8b752a",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-12-31T19:52:51.232339381Z",
  "traceSampled": true
}
```

I have no idea why my HTTP request isn't working when it comes from my front-end, it was working fine when I tested locally. I have logging of different variables in order to debug my backend and it logs if I use postman but not if I send the request from my front-end.

It’s almost as if the (I assume) pre-flight requests breaks the behaviour of the Servlet I’m hitting, and I’m not sure how to fix this

Comment: HTTP OPTIONS is commonly used by web browsers for CORS. Postman does not make CORS requests. Your code needs to handle OPTIONS requests. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: How would I handle OPTIONS requests? I’ve tried looking up how to disable sending them but methods I’ve seen don’t seem to work on my PUT request

Comment: Your question does not include code or other programming details. Read the link in my comment and Google search. HTTP OPTIONS, GET, PUT, POST, etc. are web server development 101 unless you are using a framework that hides those details.

Comment: Ended up being a CORS issue: [This answer resolved it for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45866293)